# Javascript regular expression to match an element in comma separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

I've an array

```
var myArray = [  
   {  
      "field1":"Value 1",
      "IDs":""
   },
   {  
      "field1":"Value 2",
      "IDs":"123"
   },
   {  
      "field1":"Value 3",
      "IDs":"1233; 222"
   }
];
```

And a variable to filter records against

```
var filterID = 123;
```

In the array, the IDs could be empty or have a single value or multiple values separated by semicolon. The result should always return all blank IDs plus all matching ones. So:
filterID = 123 should return 'Value 1' and 'Value 2' but not 'Value 3'.

Obviously I can't check if each IDs contains fitlerID with string comparison, as it should also return 'Value 3'. The '1233' contains '123'.

One way is to split each IDs string and remove semicolons and compare against each bit.

However, I was wondering if there is a simpler way to check using Regular Expressions?

ie what regular expression would return elements of the array where id is either blank or has 123 as one of the values in a semicolon separated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boundary marker `\b` and an OR (`|`) against an empty string:

```
/\b123\b|^$/
```

This means that `123` will match only if it is an entire word (i.e., surrounded by characters other than `[A-Za-z0-9_]`), and `^$` will catch an empty string. [More info on the `\b` marker here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Here's a [**demo of the regex**](https://regex101.com/r/iH9wG5/1) and a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wc6109zo/1/) with a sample function.

Comment: Why do you check for empty string? `\b123\b` should do the job

Comment: @MaxZoom From the question: "The result should always return all blank IDs plus all matching ones."

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell. How would I write that out in JS? I tried

  `str = "1233; 222";
 var test = str.match(/\b123\b|^$/);
 console.log(test);`

That returns undefined.

Comment: @EmilyRose Well, in that example, there are no matches. `1233` doesn't match `\b123\b`, and it isn't empty, so `test` is undefined. I added a fiddle to my answer showing how you could implement this.

Comment: Thanks so much @EdCottrell. Sorry just saw the fiddle link after I posted.. that was a super quick response.. you're genius! Many thanks.